# How to find list prices for HP Enterprise Storage kit

Tags: hp

According to the resellers I deal with, HP have to publish list prices for all of their hardware and software.  Now, I know list prices are meaningless to some extent, as the discount rates can exceed 50% at times, depending on month-end, year-end, promotions, atmospheric pressure, Etc., but they are useful for comparing vendor X and Y.

I'm currently trying to track down list prices for 3PAR StorServ kit (7400 to be specific).  I've had more luck using Google, pointing at HP.COM than HP's site itself.  However, all I've come across is an out-of-date Excel spread sheet aimed at resellers.

Anyone out there know which route to take through HP's storage site (hp.com/storage), to get to 3PAR StorServ list prices?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: My best suggestion is to call your HP sales rep.

Comment: Don't quite agree with the "on hold" status.  The question is a genuine one for any folks in the real World of IT.  No, the answer isn't a technical one, and no, I'm not after product details, just any hints from people that may have managed to navigate HP's sprawling mass of a web site.  The answer could be useful to others.  Right, I'll step off my soap box.

Comment: I agree and threw a reopen vote at it.

Comment: This is the type of situation where you need an inside channel to help navigate pricing. It's true that prices you find online won't be helpful. I could help in this specific case, but that's just how things are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.hp.com/hpinfo/newsroom/press_kits/2012/HPDiscoverFrankfurt2012/HP_StoreServ_FactSheet_Discover2012.pdf

> The HP 3PAR StoreServ 7200 redefines
>   the midrange with enterprise
>   - class functionality from $20,000 . The quad
>   - controller capable HP 3PAR StoreServ 7400 delivers Tier 1 storage starting at $32,000 .

and:

http://www.infoworld.com/d/data-center/review-hp-3par-conjures-powerful-storage-magic-218133

> The HP 3PAR StoreServ 7400 system I tested was configured with four
>   control nodes, six disk cages containing 46 SAS physical disks and 24
>   Nearline (NL) disks. List price for the system as tested is $235,000
>   before discounting. Basic configurations start at $35,000 for a
>   bare-bones system with four control nodes. For network connectivity,
>   there's 10GbE and 8Gb Fibre Channel. FCoE is in the works.

and:

```
Industry Standard Servers Support   2782    QR485A  HP 3PAR StoreServ 7400 4-N Storage Base 42168.00    39216.00
```

from: http://www.hp.com/canada/govonline/provincial/pricing/hp_pscustomer.xls